# What int should I pass into an ArrayAdapter constructor if I am not using an xml resource?

Tags: android

All of the constructors for an ArrayAdapter have an int parameter for the layout resource id you want to use when instantiating views. However sometimes you want to instantiate the views from scratch without using an xml resource. I've been passing android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 in this situation, but this doesn't seem like the correct thing to do if I'm not using that resource. What is the correct integer to pass in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct integer to pass in this situation?

Anything. `0` if you like. So long as you are not chaining to the base `ArrayAdapter` implementation of `getView()`, that value should not be used, based upon [the current implementation of `ArrayAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java).

Comment: That answers my question. I was worried that passing 0 or -1 or something might be risky if the resource doesn't exist, but your answer makes clear the int is simply ignored. Thanks very much!