# super constructor in CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am following the following [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). I am learning how to use/create a custom adapter. In the following code, super constructor is confusing me a little bit.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
   public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
       super(context, 0, users);
      }   
    ......
}
```

When I use simple `ArrayAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` constructor takes 3 paramaters : `context`, `resource`, and `list`.

```
ArrayAdapter<string> myArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleItem1, myList)
```

The following super constructor also takes 3 paramaters, but the confusing part is the second argument which is 0. What does 0 represent in the following super constructor?

```
super(context, 0, users);
```

Comment: Here zero represents the The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views

Comment: Ok I understand that is resource id, but I want to know what 0 represent ? Any reference? For example if I put 1, then is there a meaning for it?

Comment: in the case of the tutorial is as good as any other int, since the inflater happens when getView is called, and the tutorial is not calling super.getView, the value is ignored

Comment: Thanks a lot Blackbelt, apart from the tutorial, 0 represents that I am not  providing any layout. What if I use 1? Please disregard `customadapter` for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the resource ID for a layout file containing your layout when the adapter will instantiate views. Why not reading the documentation first?

Comment: Ok I understand that is resource id, but I want to know what 0 represent ? Any reference? For example if I put 1, then is that refer to something ?

Comment: 0 represents a default value. It's like telling the adapter: "I'm not giving you my layout's res ID because I will handle it myself(or something similar)"

Comment: Thanks Mike, it is what I need to know. Is there a chart/documentation for it? For example, am I allowed to pass 1 ?

Comment: @AndreaBanderas I asked exactly that question myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538679/what-int-should-i-pass-into-an-arrayadapter-constructor-if-i-am-not-using-an-xml The guy who answered my question knows what he's talking about by the way.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it is really useful. There is no explanation in the tutorial and I really want to digest the tutorial, therefore I wanted to get useful information from SOF community.

Comment: @AndreaBanderas No worries. I'm glad it helped.